# How can you go to the next record set when clicking an image using will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, pagination

I am using rails 3 and will_paginate to browse through photos. I have it working except I would also like it so that users can view the next record by clicking the picture rather than the next button in the pagination navigation. Very similar to facebooks image viewing or something like the following: http://exposure.blogocracy.org/demos/demo1.html

I don't know if will_paginate has any parameters to allow this to work... any help or direction would be very much appreciated

controller - image - action: gallery

```
def gallery
  @images = Image.all.paginate(:per_page => 1, :page => params[:page])
end
```

view image - gallery

```
<div id="slideshow">
  <% @images.each do |image| %>
    <%= image_tag("gallery/"+image.path, :alt => "") %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

view layout - _nav

```
<%= will_paginate @images,   :previous_label => '&laquo; ',
                              :next_label     => '&raquo;',
                              :params => { :controller => "images",
                                           :action => "gallery" },
                              :separator      => ' ',
                              :inner_window   => 4,
                              :outer_window   => -1           %>
```

-----------EDIT--------------

As a work around I decided to use javascript / jquery and link it manual.. it's really really ugly but im using it until i figure out the right way to do it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div#slideshow img').live('click', function() {
    var has_images = '<%= @has_image %>';
    if( has_images == 1 ) {
      var page = '<%= @next_image.id %>';
      var url = '/images/gallery?page='+page
      window.location.replace(url);
    }
    else {
      var url = '/images/gallery?page=1'
      window.location.replace(url);
    }

  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The example you are linking to is a jQuery plugin called [Exposure](http://code.google.com/p/exposure/) why don't you just use that?

And i wouldn't recommend Will_paginate for that you want.

Oluf Nielsen

Comment: Thanks for your reply Oluf! I am not sure if Exposure can handle pagination with active record as easily as will_paginate.. I did however use some really bad jquery code as a work around until i figure out a better solution.